# Angular ui-sortable not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-sortable

I'm currently working on an [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) app that contains some tests. In some of them I have a list that the user has to order correctly by dragging and dropping.

I'm using [angular-ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) to accomplish that. On PC and laptop it works perfectly. The problems arrives when the user is on a mobile devicesit's, then it stops working.

I could imagine that it conflicts with vertical scroll on phones, or am I totally wrong? And has anybody encountered this issue as well and has come up with a solution? Or might point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

**HTML** (my html if needed)

```
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="sequence" class="list-group list-group-lg list-group-sp">
    <li ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="list-group-item" draggable="true">
        <h5>{{choice.name}}</h5>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey @Backer ,did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation and the issues opened on the github repo you can add jquery-ui to solve this problem. You can check this [pen](https://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/wzmvJv) from the project README for reference.

Here is the code used for it on the pen:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="floatleft">
    <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list" class="list">
      <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item">
        {{item.text}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    update: function(e, ui) {
      var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i){
        return i.value;
      }).join(', ');
      $scope.sortingLog.push('Update: ' + logEntry);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      // this callback has the changed model
      var logEntry = tmpList.map(function(i){
        return i.value;
      }).join(', ');
      $scope.sortingLog.push('Stop: ' + logEntry);
    }
  };
```